# removeFromSuperview crash if don't use UIViewAnimation

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I meet a strange problem. I use removeFromSuperview cause my app crush. but if I use [UIView animationWithDuration], it's gone be ok.

see below  This can be run successful.

```
   [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void){

         CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
         transition.type = kCATransitionReveal;
         transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
         transition.duration = 0.5;
         [self.view.superview.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];


     } completion:^(BOOL finished){
         [self.view removeFromSuperview];
         [self removeFromParentViewController];
     }] ;
```

but if I remove the [UIView animationWithDuration] like this.

```
    [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

     [self.view removeFromSuperview];
     [self removeFromParentViewController];
```

It's gone be crashed.

and here is how I add the subview

```
 [self.tabBarController addChildViewController: vc];
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
transition.duration = 0.5;
[self.tabBarController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:vc.view];
[self.tabBarController didMoveToParentViewController:vc];
```

I have no idea why this happened. Hope someone can help me .  It's a weird problem.
[image]

Comment: It'll help if you add the crash message as well.

Comment: There is no crash message in output, only stop and the Xcode will navigate to the assembly language.

Comment: Are you adding the `transition` to the `self.view.superview.layer` before `[self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];` ?

Comment: no,do I have to add a transition. the problem here is it will stopped if i don't use the UIView animation. 
[self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

     [self.view removeFromSuperview];
     [self removeFromParentViewController];
you mean  I need to add a transition here  even if I don't use any animation?

Comment: No, you don't have to add a transition. My bet is that if you'll do `[self.view removeFromSuperview]; [self removeFromParentViewController];` after a 0.5 seconds delay won't crash, and I was thinking that maybe you add the transition animation, since that's 0.5 seconds too.

Comment: The crash is probably occuring because you are try to remove a view whose animation are still not finished